# WebGL video background

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video, webgl

Is there any possibility to have a video playing in background for a WebGL? I tried with `z-index` and `pointer-events` but canvas background is black, even with `background-color:transparent` doesn't work. Here is the original [codepen](https://codepen.io/RustamWD/pen/jYLXZm)

In js tab on line 49 is a line that I think set's the background color:

```
gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
```

changin last number that I think is the opacity to 0 does not make it transparent. Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mGvJwP)

Comment: First avoid to disable the alpha in the params of canvas.getContext.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a little bit, but when I move the mouse background get black again, I think that onmousemove event somehow sets the background again until animation ends.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, maybe someone will need that too,

```
alpha: false, -> true;
```

line 132> `gl_FragColor = vec4(base + splat, 1.0); -> gl_FragColor = vec4(base + splat, 0.0);`

Thanks to Kaiido for first tip.